How to revoke consent for a registered app programmatically?
I have a very simple application where users can sync their calendars and also receive new events directly into the calendar. I acquire "Calendars.ReadWrite, offline_access, User.Read" delegated permissions interactively.
When the users decide to stop using my application, they can "unlink" and I will drop all the events, hooks, etc. What I am trying to achieve is that my third-party app would also disappear from the list of apps presented here: https://account.live.com/consent/Manage. In other words, a complete cleanup, revoking any access permissions, dropping all tokens, etc.
I've been struggling with this issue for days. Tried many different endpoints and mostly got back cryptic errors only. Overall, zero progress. I am running out of ideas about what I can do with revokeSignInSessions and oAuth2PermissionGrant; it seems like I tried everything and nothing worked. So, I really hope that someone here can help me out.
It seems a very basic scenario. Google Calendar has a simple endpoint that can do exactly that: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token=. What am I missing? How can I do that? It must be a common requirement, no?
Thanks for reading this post! Any help is appreciated.
Regards,

Assume you have an app registration named Revoke Demo that requests the permissions you list in your question.

The note at the bottom of screen capture tells you that you can see consented permissions by going to Enterprise applications. If you search for Revoke Demo in the Entra ID Enterprise applications, you'd find the page associated with the app registration. Note where you can find the Object ID for the Enterprise application, you'll need it later.

If you expand Security and select Permissions in the left navigation, and then select the User consent tab, you can see the permissions that have been granted for this application.

You can get the same information using Microsoft Graph by making a GET request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/oauth2PermissionGrants where the id is the Object ID of the Enterprise application.

Note, in my demo only one user had consented permission for the application so there is only one oAuth2PermissionGrant object returned. If multiple users had consented permissions then there would be one object per user. You can determine which user the oAuth2PermissionGrant object applies to using the value of the principalId property.
To revoke permissions, issue a DELETE request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oAuth2PermissionGrants/{id} where the id is the id of the the appropriate oAuth2PermissionGrant object returned from the previous request.

You can then use the Microsoft Graph or the Enterprise application page in the Azure portal to confirm that the permissions have been revoked.

Please note the permissions required to perform these requests. This screen capture is taken from the documentation linked below.

For more information, see Review permissions granted to enterprise applications and select the Microsoft Graph option at the top of the page.

Hi, Rob. Thank you for your reply. But this thing revokes access permissions on my app. That's not what I am looking for. In my case, Revoke Demo will be used by unknown/distrusted users who will delegate access permissions to their calendars to Revoke Demo. And at some point they might want to revoke the "consent". However, Revoke Demo should work as expected for everyone else. Do you know what I mean?

I can see what might have lead to the confusion. The DELETE request doesn't revoke all permissions, just those for a specific user.
In my demo only one user had consented permission for the application so there was only one oAuth2PermissionGrant object returned in the first Graph Explorer call. If multiple users had consented permissions then there would be one object per user. You can determine which user the oAuth2PermissionGrant object applies to using the value of the principalId property.
I've added this information into the body of the answer.

I got admin permissions for granting consent and I can confirm that your example works as presented for "internal" users. In other words, if I am the app user and also a tenant user, I can see my permissions and revoke them. However, it seems that we are not talking about the same thing here. I would like that an app user who is not our tenant user, let's call her Anonymous, is able to get permissions revoked programmatically.

You can also imagine that you, Rob Windsor, are using my Calendar synchronizer (and you delegated permissions for that to the Revoke Demo app). Now you are leaving the platform and want to "unlink" the calendar. I would like to revoke the consent you gave without expecting any extra effort from you. Please let me know if I am being clear enough about what I am looking for.
